# achieve azure application gateway reverse proxy capability similar to nginx

Tags: nginx, azure-application-gateway

Currently i don't believe the Azure Application gateway (WAF V2) has reverse proxy capability like a dedicated nginx VM, which fetches data from a backend or some external website and displays content in the frontend URL which does not change in the URL bar.

E.g.
Proxy all requests from https://www.abcd.com/test to get a response from backend (or external website) at https://example.com and display the content from https://example.com at https://www.abcd.com/test

abcd.com for e.g. is an Azure web app, and example.com is some third party from whom we wish to display content from.

Or am i wrong, and we do have some way of achieving this with just an application gateway?

To achieve this we setup a nginx VM and have it added as a backend pool in the Azure application gateway. We have added a rule to detect and apply a path based redirect for "/test" and send it a backend pool which has the IP address of the nginx VM we set up.

The nginx config is as follows there:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_pass https://example.com/;
proxy_buffering off;
```

Anybody got any ideas how we can use a Rewrite set in application gateway to achieve this instead of using a nginx VM to do this, or should we stick with nginx and the capability is not supported by Azure application gateway yet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-url-portal, though Application gateway is designed to work as a reverse proxy but unfortunately, that capability is not possible at the moment. Your best option is still Nginx.